# Notation for signatures

Tags: logic, notation

A (multi-sorted) signature consists of some sort symbols, say $X$ and $Y$, together with some constant symbols, say $0,1 : X$, some function symbols, say $f : X \times Y \rightarrow X$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Y,$ and some relation symbols.

What notation is standard for the relation symbols? For example, if $R$ is meant to denote a binary relation on $X$, how would I write this? The notation $R : 2^{X \times X}$ is tempting, but I'd prefer to use standard notation if it exists.

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen the $\subseteq$ symbol used: $R \subseteq X \times X$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of multiple sorts is very common type theory. In that context, if "Bool" is the type consisting of the truth value $\{T, F\}$, then a binary relation on $X$ would be of type $X \times X \to \text{Bool}$.